# For which $u$ does the derivative $f'(u,0)$ of $f(x,y)=|x|+|y|$ exist?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

**Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by setting $f(x,y)=|x|+|y|$**

**(a) For which vectors $u\ne 0$ does $f'(0; u)$ exist? Evaluate it when it
exists.**

**(b) Do $D_1f$ and $D_2f$ exist at $0$?**

**(c) Is $f$ differentiable at $0$?**

**(d) Is $f$ continuous at $0$?**

I have thought a lot about this problem:

For (a), be $u\neq 0, u:=(h,k)$, then $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(0+tu)-f(0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(th,tk)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{|th|+|tk|}{t}=(|h|+|k|)\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{|t|}{t}$ and just as $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{|t|}{t}$ does not exist, necessarily $h=k=0$, with which no directional derivative exists, this immediately tells us that in (b) neither $D_1f$ and $D_2f$ exist and that $f$ is not differentiable in $(0,0)$. Also clearly $f$ is continuous in $(0,0)$. Is this reasoning correct? Could someone help me by giving me suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: This is correct except that you might want to elaborate on the continuity.

Comment: @KittyL $\lim_{(x,y)\to 0}f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y)\to 0}|x|+|y|=|0|+|0|=0$ and $f(0,0)= |0|+|0|=0$ so $f$ is continuous